# Fast K-nearest neighbor search with Haversine Distance in R

Tags: r, distance, knn

For some reason, I have to find the 10~30 nearest neighbors for each samples in a geo-dataset(have lat, lon, and some categorical features, rows >10M) with various kinds of distance metrics, mostly Haversine Distance or Gower Distance.

Here, I need a fast implementation/package for obtaining the **index** and **actual distance** of the samples for each data point. Actually, the function `get.knn` in `FNN` package works very well and it meets my requirements. Unfortunately, it does not support custom distance settings and only provides euclidean distance.

I was wondering that is there any other package that can perform knn at least with Haversine Distance and output the index and distance in a very fast manner?

Many thanks!